# conf.d/python.d/ is not available in datadog-agent

Tags: python, datadog

I was trying to install `data-dog` agent in my `Ubuntu 20.04` for monitoring a python backend with the following command

```sh
DD_AGENT_MAJOR_VERSION=7 DD_API_KEY=xxxxxxxxx DD_SITE="datadoghq.com" bash -c "$(curl -L https://s3.amazonaws.com/dd-agent/scripts/install_script.sh)"
```

From the [official documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/python/?tab=jsonlogformatter) it says

```
Create a file conf.yaml in the Agent’s conf.d/python.d/ directory with the following
```

But haven't found any `python.d` inside `/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d`.  If I create the `python.d/con.yaml` do I need to do anything else for enabling sending logs?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question this might be helpful for others

I had to set

```
logs_enabled: true
```

inside `/etc/datadog-agent/datadog.yaml` then I've created `python.d/conf.yaml` with the following configs

```
init_config:

instances:

##Log section
logs:

  - type: file
    path: "<PATH_TO_PYTHON_LOG>.log"
    service: "<YOUR_APPLICATION>"
    source: python
    sourcecategory: sourcecode
    # For multiline logs, if they start by the date with the format yyyy-mm-dd uncomment the following processing rule
    #log_processing_rules:
    #  - type: multi_line
    #    name: new_log_start_with_date
    #    pattern: \d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

Restart the agent with

```
sudo service datadog-agent restart
```

You can see your logs in the dashboard logs panel